# Fatal Error relating to sessions.php

Tags: php, session, fatal-error, settings-api

here is the error code I have

> Warning: Unterminated comment starting line 2079 in
>   /home/teamspor/public_html/wp-includes/user.php on line 2079
>
> Warning: require(/home/teamspor/public_html/wp-includes/session.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /home/teamspor/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 122
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/home/teamspor/public_html/wp-includes/session.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in
>   /home/teamspor/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 122

I have tried deleting the theme from the ftp and I have also tried disabling the plug-ins via the same method. The only advice I've found online so far is advising to add/change bits of code but it doesn't say where. As far as I can tell it's some sort of permissions issue but I'm not sure why it has happened.

The "settings.php" file is in the correct place but the "sessions.php" file is missing

Comment: How did this error first appear? Does other themes (like native WP ones) work?

Comment: Looks like an incomplete update. Please update WordPress manually and test again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by:

1) checking wordpress version in: `/home/myusername/public_html/version.php`

2) downloading this version package from wordpress website

3) adding`wp-includes/session.php` file from downloaded package into `/home/myusername/public_html/wp-includes/session.php` (that file was empty or not existing)